# Infinite sum of Legendre Polynomials

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, legendre-polynomials

The infinite sum of a single Legendre Polynomial has a well known expression. Are there any explicit formulas for the infinite sum of the product of two Legendre Polynomials? I'm interested on polynomials of both First and Second kind (usually denoted $P_l$ and $Q_l$ respectively).

$\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} P_l(x)P_l(y)= ?$

$\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} P_l(x)Q_l(y)= ?$

and variants of this, like inserting $(i)^l$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sums are not 'nice', no abs convergence anywhere. Assuming that normalization of $P_k$ is such that $\int_{-1}^1 P_k(x)P_l(x)dx=\delta_{kl}$ your first expression converges weakly to the identity in $L^2$, i.e. 
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-1}^1 \left (\sum_{l=0}^n P_l(x) P_l(y) \right)\; f(y) \; dy = f(x)$$
for a.e. $x$ (I think) but at least with convergence in $L^2$ (for sure). In a distributional sense the limit is $\delta(x-y)$.
For the second I don't know what it gives. Is this in the direction you wanted?

Answer (score -1):

Some useful properties of Legendre polynomials and its applications to neutron transport equation in slab geometry,by F. Anli and S. Güngör, Appl. Math. Modelling   https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0307904X05002660